# Live search in html table using cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I used this code to live search in table:

```
$search.keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $.each($table.find('tbody'), function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) == -1)
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```

It worked great, but now I have 1000+ rows in table and searching is really slow on older machines so I created array from table:

```
function getTableData() {
    var data = [];
    $table.find('tbody').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
        var cols = [];
        $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {
            cols.push(c.textContent);
        });
        data.push(cols);
    });
    return data;
};
```

And I don't know how to search same way in this array to get tbody index.

Comment: add a fiddle for your problem.

Comment: There's only one 'tbody' in a table and you are using `each` for that makes no sense for me. (this makes slow too)

Comment: No, I have more tbody in table and each contain one or more rows (tr). It's essential for my work.

Comment: You could try using Vanilla javascript, since speed is your problem?

Comment: table shouldn't be more than one tbody...

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hh6aed45/.

Comment: I heard about Vanilla javascript, but I'd like to solve this problem with an array, which should be fast as well. And yes, table can have more than one tbody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 3 Update uses cache and a hidden results box;

Here we hide the table, and create a results list on the fly, please note the html markup is very simple and incorrect but it demonstrates the speed improvements of not touching the dom when we cycle our memory cache, the next improvement would be to cache the html of each row and have it in our cache object, thus no need to get the row from the dom when it matches.

http://jsfiddle.net/hh6aed45/5/

```
var $search = $('input[type="text"]');
var $table = $('table');
var $result = document.getElementById("search");


var i=1;

function uuid(){
   i++;
   return "A"+i;
};


$search.keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim(), html="";

    for (row in cache) {
    // the getElementById can be speeded up by caching the html in our memory cache!  
    if (cache[row].indexOf(value) !== -1) html+=document.getElementById(row).innerHTML;
    }
    $result.innerHTML=html;
});



function getTableData() {
    var cache = {};
    $table.find('tbody').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
        $(this).find("tr").each(function(rowIndex,r){
        var cols = [], id = uuid();
        r.id=id;
        $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {
        cols.push(c.textContent);
        });
        cache[id]=cols.join(" ").toLowerCase();
    });    
});
return cache;
```

};

var cache = getTableData();

## 2 Update uses just a memory cache!

http://jsfiddle.net/hh6aed45/3/

This caches the dom as you requested, I add a uuid as an id so that the search can find each row, i could of cached an object and included a live reference to the dom. in fairness as I said I would only switch on what filters in and switch in the minority, as that would speed the loop as no Dom changes would occur for all rows that are not matching, which out of 10,000 would be many. I would also toggle a css class for "in" and "out", that would allow a live list to be cached of all in items, which then could be hidden before the search starts. So in basic, hide all 10,000 rows, turn on what matches, thus the loop does not touch the Dom unless it has! That is about as fast as you will get it.

```
var $search = $('input[type="text"]');
var $table = $('table');

var i=1;

function uuid(){
   i++;
   return "A"+i;
};


$search.keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    for (row in cache) {
        document.getElementById(row).style.display = (cache[row].indexOf(value) === -1) ?     "none" : "table-row";
    }
});



function getTableData() {
    var cache = {};
    $table.find('tbody').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
    $(this).find("tr").each(function(rowIndex,r){
    var cols = [], id = uuid();
    r.id=id;
    $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {
        cols.push(c.textContent);
    });
    cache[id]=cols.join(" ").toLowerCase();
    });    
    
    
});
return cache;
};
```

var cache = getTableData();

## 1 uses native raw javascript with optimizations;

For this kind of thing plane java-script is a must, if your talking about performance first things first, throw jquery out in your loop. Cache the dom first, dont keep loading it.

Speed is an illusion when your building programs.

For example you could do the lookup after two or three letters, not one. You could also change the code so that if a row does not match it is skipped, not switched into view.

so step one turn all rows on, (find all rows that are off, cache the view as views are live)

step two remove rows, not turn rows on and off as you go, that will speed the loop. here is

a sped up version walking the dom, if we had 10,000 rows two test we could improve and improve.

Here is a starting point, from here we use the steps as suggested above:

```
var $search = $('input[type="text"]'),
    $table = $('table'),
    $body = $table.find('tbody')
    $rows = $body.find('tr'); // this view of the dom is live!
$search.keyup(function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

   //loops are costly, native is ultra fast

   for (var i = 0; l=$rows.length, i < l; i++) {
        $rows[i].style.display= ($rows[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1) ?     "none" : "table-row";
   }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hh6aed45/

Comment: Martin, thanks for your advices. I tested your pure js solution with few improvements but although I know for loop is way faster than each loop, I didn't get any significant enhancement in my case. That is why I try to search through an array. Anyway thanks...

Comment: OK. What need I is a fiddle with a lot more data to test. For sure a cache will sort the problem, but that cache needs to be a little more complex than that, that your propose. If you want me to make it work as fast as it can, and I'm confident I can make big speed changes, put more html table data in the fiddle, and i'll work some magic.

Comment: OK Martin, give it a try :) Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0cy4wdj2/. In my browser it takes about 20ms but on my client's PC (Windows XP, Firefox) it takes 2-3 seconds with every letter.

Comment: I have added a new solution to my answer it uses a cache as you requested. Try that out with your data. I have the new fiddle. If it still does not come up to pace on your clients machine as I said their other other ways to speed it up. Right now it touches the dom for every row, that it a major speed bloat especially on older pc, small devices, browsers.

Comment: Also note my code adds a ID to each, your data has one, omit my uuid() code and pick out the id of the row.

Comment: Another solution: Cache the rows as per my example. Create a hidden div below the search box, when the user types hide the table with the 1000 rows, show the div, scour the cache as per my example, add the html or each row that matches, place that in the hidden div. This completely removes any dom iteration, it speeds the loop and removes the need to turn on and off rows. On key press if the entry is empty show the table again and clear the divs innerHTML ready for the next search.

Comment: I have added 3 examples - native code, memory cache, hidden search results list (which is the fastest) as per my comment above.

Comment: Wow, with your cache solution it's 20 times faster in my browser. I'll try other your advices and let's see what happens. It's great to learn something new. Thanks a lot Martin, very helpful.

Comment: The solutions i have provided are just quick alternatives, a roled out production version could look on any device like it was instant, lots of tricks can be used to make your app, web page seem like it is on steroids. Try to use native code where you can, as the user experience is what makes you apps have the wow factor, glad to be of service.

Comment: It's noticeably faster now :) Could I ask you for last advice? How would you count visible rows on every keyup?

Comment: I would not use a production version with a raw keyup, google search and other implementations of live search use a delay timer, as this adds a hack that threads the code. To get a count is simple; whatever solution you use just do c++; as a counter each time you find a match and when the search is done, display that count back to the dom. Don't forget even that count will slow your code, so think about how to do it without slowing the code. best bet is the "switching" technique where you switch the table out and switch a results div in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly add delay timer as you suggest.