# JQuery Tablesorter Slow Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 tables on a single view, all of which use tablesorter. The issue i'm having is that one of the tables has a lot of records, specifically about 3000. Because of this it takes about 17 seconds to load. I tried delayinit, but it didn't seem to speed things up at all. I'm using the paging plugin. Is there a way I can make it so only x amount of pages initially load? If all it has to load is the first 5 records, it should be really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you tried preloading the script before the user gets to this page? Or are you unable to do to it being the initial screen? There is concerns about it effecting the performance of the user screen before this one needs to be loaded but you can do the preload after the first screen is done allowing it to process in the background before the table is even needed...

```
 window.onload = function () {  
 preload = [ 'http://www.example.com/script1.js', 'http://www.example.com/script2.js' ]  
};
```

Comment: The tablesorter scripts are in the cshtml view. Should I just seperate the two and reference the jquery in that preload function?

Comment: well a cshtml file should be doing the preloading for you.  Razor's purpose is to make more RESTful "web-based" platforms.  You would want your JQuery to be immediate on the first page... have the first page load.. the preload the next page's table.  This is why big tables are never really used on initial pages and a search is used... the users search criteria goes into the preloader and starts compiling before the user can hit send.

Comment: I'm using a similar function to load a picture of the table, until the table is fully loaded, to try to trick the user. Otherwise they're sitting in a white screen for up to 25s, and that's in chrome which is the fastest. It always takes just as long to load when going back to it, which i don't understand cause it should be cached and be fast. is there a way i can keep it in memory so it doesn't have to reformat the data when i return to the page?

Comment: yes it is known as 'memoize'.  This article might help a little understanding how to go about it. http://krisjordan.com/refactor-with-memoize; and...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241724/live-search-in-html-table-using-cache